# Получение данных пользователя node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

я только начал изучать javscript. Столкнулся с проблемой, информацию о которой найти не могу. У меня есть задача: Создать страницу регистрации, авторизации и профиля с применением node js, express, и занести данные в бд MySQL. Я сверстал frontend первых двух страниц с применением input'ов. Из них я хочу получить данные пользователя, но чтобы это сделать мне не хватает знаний. вот собственно html код:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Play-Bold";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: bold;
  src: local(Play-Bold), url(../fonts/Play-Bold.ttf);
}

body {
  background-color: #515152;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Play-Bold";
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  padding: 13px 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 0;
}

input {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #3a3a3b;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.form h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px 100px;
}

.log {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #262626;
}

.reg {
  height: 730px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #262626;
}

.btn-1:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: #9a9b9c;
}

.btn-2:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: #9a9b9c;
}

.link-a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #a9aaab;
}


/*ПРОФИЛЬ*/

.cont {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.profile {
  background-color: #3a3a3b;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bgop"></div>
  <form action="/register" class="form" id="myform">
    <div class="reg">
      <h1>Регистрация</h1>
      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="login"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="userName" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="lastname"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Фамилия" name="lastname" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="patronymic"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Отчество" name="patronymic" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
      </div>


      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="login"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Логин" name="login" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="password"></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" name="password" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="repeat-password"></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Повторите пароль" name="repeatPassword" required>
      </div>

      <h2>Паспортные данные:</h2>

      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="series"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Серия" name="series" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-form">
        <label for="number"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Номер" name="number" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-form">
        <button class="btn-2">Зарегистрироваться</button>
      </div>

      <a href="log.html" class="link-a">Уже есть аккаунт?</a>
    </div>

  </form>

  <script src="../Node js/server.js">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Я буду безмерно благодарен, если кто-то мне объяснит что делать. Все что я нашел в интернете не помогает и слишком неясно написано

Answer (score 1):

Могу вкратце описать порядок действий:

1. Создать nodejs приложение, в которое импортировать express, sequelize (для упрощенной работы с БД);
2. Скачать сервер для mysql и создать базу данных (нужно только название);
3. В приложении описать подключение к БД (в конфигурации sequelize) и описать модели, просто пишете все нужные поля, таблицы (хорошо этого процесс описан в документации sequelize);
4. Берете из express роутер, который будет получать /register и брать из req.body все нужные поля (название в атрибуте name в форме), также аналогично создаете все необходимые действия: регистрация, авторизация, профиль и т.д.;
5. Сохраняете данные в БД (Account - это созданная вами ранее модель sequelize): `await Account.create({ name, lastname, ... })`.

Comment: Привет, спасибо за помощь. На данный момент я почти закончил работу с MySQL. У меня возникла еще одна проблема. Она связана с подключение cookie файлов. Вроде код правильный, но cookie всё равно не работает. Был бы рад услышать ваш совет еще раз.

Comment: Ваше объяснение не до конца понятно, что конкретно не работает. Потому что куки на фронте - это встроенная возможность, на беке есть множество библиотек для работы с ними. В каком конкретно моменте не работает.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, поэтому создал отдельный вопрос под эту проблему, где описал ее подробней. Если вы знакомы с этой системой, то был бы рад вашему мнению